# Can't print a 10 from .format() in superscript in tex in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tex

In matplotlib I'm creating a series of graphs using the following code.
When I plot it, the calculated superscripts from 1 to 9 render correctly, but in x^10 through x^12, only the 1 is in the superscript, the following digit (0, 1, 2) is on the same line as the x :

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=6, figsize = (14,4.5))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.set_title("$x^{}$".format(i+1))
    ax.plot(x,  x**(i+1))
    
fig.tight_layout();
```

How do I get it to put all the digits in the superscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```py
    ax.set_title("$x^{}$".format(i+1))
```

with

```py
    ax.set_title("$x^{{{}}}$".format(i+1))
```

Matplotlib supports the use of (some) LaTeX expressions in axis titles. In LaTeX, the `^` character causes the next character, or group, to be formatted in superscript. When processing `x^10`, LaTeX will only set the `1` in superscript, leaving the `0` on the same line as the `x`, but when processing `x^{10}` it will set `10` in superscript because `10` is inside the group that the braces `{` and `}` surround.  (If it didn't do this, how would it know when the superscript ended?)

When `.format` encounters `{{` and `}}`, it takes them to mean that you want an actual `{` or `}` character in the resulting string, and that they are not part of a placeholder it has to fill with a value.  The `{}` in the middle of `"$x^{{{}}}$"` is interpreted as the placeholder.

You end up with three pairs of braces, because it happens that `{` and `}` characters have a meaning to both the `.format` method and to LaTeX.